# Making sure custom tag does not have subtags

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, custom-tag

I am building custom tag to wrap around glyphicons.

```
 <b:icon binding="i" />
```

Part of the Glyphicon spec includes:

Only for use on empty elements

> Icon classes should only be used on elements that contain no text
>   content and have no child elements.

I want to make sure no one does something like

```
 <b:icon binding="i">
    <cfset myVariable++>
 </b:icon>
```

Is there a way to make sure a custom tag does not have any inner tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have two options that I can see.

First, throw an exception if `thisTag.executionMode` is anything other than `"start"`. Or one could likewise throw an exception if `thisTag.hasEndTag` is `true`. However this will restrict tag usage to:

```
<b:icon binding="i">
```

And *not*:

```
<b:icon binding="i" />
```

Because `/>` is shorthand for an end-tag. This is less than ideal, and you perhaps won't accept that as an approach.

Secondly you can check if there's any `generatedContent` but this is a big haphazard because it's entirely possible to have something between starting and closing tags, but is careful to not generate content:

```
<b:icon binding="i"><cfset foo="bar"></b:icon>
```

(note: even the new lines and indentation would count as `generatedContent` if there were any).

Bottom line: whilst JSP custom tags allow for control of this sort of thing, I cannot see how it can be controlled by the CFML implementation. The closest you can get is to prohibit closing tags entirely.